# CSS3 perspective transform is not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a css transform for dropdown menu, but it does not work in firefox, 
from other posts, I tried this:

```
...
 -moz-animation: flipInX 3s;
...
```

but it doesn't work in firefox.
this is the test test page:

http://leamratech.com/test/test/test.html

Answer (score 1):

In your animation CSS alongside @-webkit-keyframes flipInX {} you need to add @-moz-keyframes flipInX {} as well. that should resolve your issue.

Comment: @-moz-keyframes flipInX {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(-10deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(-10deg);
    }

    70% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(10deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(10deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

Comment: Hey mate, you need to add -moz-transform, instead of -webkit-transform as you are dealing with mozilla.

Comment: So the full code would be like this one - @-moz-keyframes flipInX {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }.......
}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this website [HERE](http://codepen.io/macreart/pen/qtLEG) ,

It shows you the code, and it works in chrome and firefox (I tested it)
it uses `@keyframes`